# How to implement global hotkeys that work in full screen mode

Tags: c#, fullscreen, global, hotkeys

I'm creating a software that must work when user is playing game in full screen mode. When user press a hotkey it will do something. My current hotkey implementation works only in windows. I need both KeyUp && KeyDown in full screen, i'm use TheDarkJoker94's class. Please advice.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;   

public class GlobalKeyboardHook
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LLKeyboardHook callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint theardID);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

public delegate int LLKeyboardHook(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);

public struct keyBoardHookStruct
{
    public int vkCode;
    public int scanCode;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public int dwExtraInfo;
}

const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;

LLKeyboardHook llkh;
public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

IntPtr Hook = IntPtr.Zero;

public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

// This is the Constructor. This is the code that runs every time you create a new GlobalKeyboardHook object
public GlobalKeyboardHook()
{
    llkh = new LLKeyboardHook(HookProc);
    // This starts the hook. You can leave this as comment and you have to start it manually (the thing I do in the tutorial, with the button)
    // Or delete the comment mark and your hook will start automatically when your program starts (because a new GlobalKeyboardHook object is created)
    // That's why there are duplicates, because you start it twice! I'm sorry, I haven't noticed this...
    // hook(); <-- Choose!
}
~GlobalKeyboardHook()
{ unhook(); }

public void hook()
{
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, llkh, hInstance, 0);
}

public void unhook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
}

public int HookProc(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam)
{
    if (Code >= 0)
    {
        Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
        if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
        {
            KeyEventArgs kArg = new KeyEventArgs(key);
            if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                KeyDown(this, kArg);
            else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                KeyUp(this, kArg);
            if (kArg.Handled)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(Hook, Code, wParam, ref lParam);
}

}
```